# How to Divide an Array into set of 6(six) elements using java

Tags: java, arrays

I am having an Array, I want to write set of 6 (six) items into text files.

```
Array:-
[C, A2, A, E, B, D, F,A3,C1,D1,G1] 

output:-
test1.txt:-[C, A2, A, E, B, D]

test2.txt:-[F,A3,C1,D1,G1]


   Object ia[] = al.toArray(); 
      for(int i=0; i<ia.length; i++) 
      {count=1;
            for(j=0;j<=5;j++)
            {
                System.out.println("Set"+ ia[j]); 
            }
            j=j;

     //     System.out.println( ia[i]); 
      }
```

Comment: you must try to write code fist. This forum is not a place that help you do your excercise.

Comment: @hoangnguyen : I have tried some code already

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be looking for [`Arrays.copyOfRange()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange%28T%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29).

**Code snap:**

```
String[] arr = { "C", "A2", "A", "E", "B", "D", "F","A3","C1","D1","G1"  };
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, 0, 6)));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, 6, 11)));
```

Will yield (as expected):

```
[C, A2, A, E, B, D]
[F, A3, C1, D1, G1]
```

Of course you can generzalize this to invoke `copyOfRange()` in a loop with variables as the arguments (and not hard coded as the simple code snap)

Answer (score 1):

```
second_arr [] =new array[count];
for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
  if(i%count == 0 ){
   for(int j=0;j<count;j++)
         System.out.print(second_arr[j]+ " ");
  }
 second_arr[i%count]=arr[i];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [`PrintWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html) (example [here](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=329)).

You essentially loop over your array elements and each time you have reached an index which when divided by 6 yields 0, you create a new file and start writing to it.